# MongoDB - how can I pass variable or expression to $limit aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, limit, aggregation

I use this expression for limiting the number of documents, but Mongo seems not accept it (in the official document, $limit only allow Integer value). But is there any tricks to get it?

```
{ $limit: '$numQuestion', },
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. This is how I solved the problem:

```
num = 10;
{ $limit: Number(num) },
```

Answer (score -1):

So you mean this?

```
numQuestion = 10;
{ $limit: numQuestion  },
```